# Collect and run all junit tests in parallel with each test class in its own JVM (parallelization by class, not by method)

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, junit

**Problem**
I've a bunch of junit tests (many with custom runners such as PowerMockRunner or JUnitParamsRunner) all under some root package `tests` (they are in various subpackages of `tests` at various depths).

I'd like to collect all the tests under package `tests` and run each **test class** in a different JVM, in parallel. Ideally, the parallelization would be configurable, but a default of number_of_cores is totally fine as well. Note that I do not want to run each method in its own JVM, but each class.

**Background**
I'm using PowerMock combined with JUnitParams via annotations `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(JUnitParamsRunner.class)` for many of my tests. I have ~9000 unit tests which complete in an "ok" amount of time but I've an 8-core CPU and the systems is heavily underutilized with the default single-test-at-a-time runner. As I run the tests quite often, the extra time adds up and I really want to run the test classes in parallel.

Note that, unfortunately, in a good number of the tests I need to mock static methods which is part of the reason I'm using PowerMock.

**What I've Tried**
Having to mock static methods makes it impossible to use something like `com.googlecode.junittoolbox.ParallelSuite` (which was my initial solution) since it runs everything in the same JVM and the static mocking gets all interleaved and messed up. Or so it seems to me at least based on the errors I get.

I don't know the JUnit stack at all, but after poking around, it appears that another option might be to try to write and inject my own `RunnerBuilder` -- but I'm not sure if I can even spawn another JVM process from within a `RunnerBuilder`, unlikely. I think the proper solution would be some kind of harness that lives as a gradle task.

I also JUST discovered some Android Studio (Intellij's) test options but the only available fork option is `method` which is not what I want. I am currently exploring this solution so perhaps I will figure it out but I thought I'd ask the community in parallel since I haven't had much lock yet.

**UPDATE**: Finally was able to get Android Studio (Intellij) to collect all my tests using options Test Kind: `All in directory` (for some reason the package option did not do recursive searching) and picking fork mode `Class`. However, this still runs each test class found sequentially and there are no options that I see about parallelization. This is so close to what I want but not quite... :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using Intellij's (Android Studio) built-in JUnit run configurations, I noticed that Android Studio has a bunch of pre-build gradle tasks some of which refer to testing. Those however, exhibited the same sequential execution problem. I then found [Run parallel test task using gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805915/run-parallel-test-task-using-gradle) and added the following statement to my root `build.gradle` file:

```
subprojects {
    tasks.withType(Test) {
        maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
    }
}
```

This works great, my CPU is now pegged to 100% (for most of the run, as the number of outstanding test classes becomes < avail processors obviously utilization goes down).

**The downside to this solution** is that it does not integrate with Android Studio's (Intellij) pretty junit runner UI. So while the gradle task is progressing I cannot really see the rate of test completion, etc. At the end of the task execution, it just spits out the total runtime and a link to an HTML generated report. This is a minor point and I can totally live with it, but it would be nice if I could figure out how to improve the solution to use the the JUnit runner UI.

Comment: btw for those interested, the runtime went from an avg of 4min 45seconds to an avg of 2min 3seconds. reason it's not lower as expected is long tails due to a single test class that has a lot of test methods

Comment: i'm accepting this as the answer but if you have better ideas or a refined version of the answer (especially addressing the downside in bold above), i'll reward the answer to you instead and upvote, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this was not possible when the question posted but now you can do it easily in android studio.

I am using gradle build tools: `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'`

And I added the following in my root `build.gradle` file.

```
allprojects {
    // ...
    tasks.withType(Test) {
        maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
    }
}
```

Now, I have multiple `Gradle Test Executor` runners for my tests. The more cores of your running machine, the mores executors you have!

Thanks for sharing your original answer!

Comment: I set maxParallelForks = 8 and saw no decrease in time. What else did you need to do?

Comment: thanks for posting but how is your answer different from mine? :)

Comment: I think that the subproject don't working for me. But I guess this depends on your project structure.

Answer (score 0):

It may sound counterintuitive but actually **running lower number of forks may be faster than running on all available cores**.

For me this setup is 30s faster (1:50 instead of 2:20) for the same tests, compared to all available processors (8 core CPU, 16 threads)

```
subprojects {
    tasks.withType(Test) {
        maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors().intdiv(2) ?: 1
    }
}
```